# extjs4 CheckboxModel select all

Tags: extjs, checkbox, grid

I want that the CheckboxModel appear all checked when grid is rendered:
[image]

This is my code:

```
sm = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
        listeners: {
            selectionchange: function (sm, selections) {
                // Must refresh the view after every selection
                sm.view.refresh();
            }
        }
    })
```

The grid:

```
{
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            title: 'gridTitle',
            selModel: sm,
            store: my_store,
            columns: {
                items:[
                    ..
                ]
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use **afterrender** listeners of the grid to select all the rows :

```
 listeners:{
    afterrender:function( thisObj, eOpts ){
        var sm=thisObj.getSelectionModel();
        sm.selectAll(true);
    }
},
```

Comment: As Answered by Daemon it should work perfectly with 1 exception Header will not be checked but all records will be checked. Aminesrine are you getting  any errors?

Answer (score 2):

`afterrender` may not work, try `afterlayout` instead:

```
// in your grid
listeners: {
    afterlayout : function (thisObj, eOpts) {
       thisObj.getSelectionModel().selectAll();
    }
},
// ...
```